# React Native TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance with Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am learning React Native from a tutorial from Coding with Mosh. I have gotten to a problem when trying to have a list of images at the top of a product listing page. In the examples, he walks through creating the components, and eventually implementing it into a screen. I had the ImageInputList working before he tasked me with implementing it into a form. This is when the issues started. I have essentially copied his source code and I am still receiving errors. I am just trying to understand why this is happening a bit more in-depth so that I can change how it is implemented.

**Component that handles a tap and if selected, renders an Image (ImageInput.js):**

```
function ImageInput({ imageUri, onChangeImage }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    requestPermission();
  }, []);

  const requestPermission = async () => {
    const { granted } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync();
    if (!granted) alert("You need to enable permission to access the library.");
  };

  const handlePress = () => {
    if (!imageUri) selectImage();
    else
      Alert.alert("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete this image?", [
        { text: "Yes", onPress: () => onChangeImage(null) },
        { text: "No" },
      ]);
  };

  const selectImage = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        quality: 0.5,
      });

      if (!result.cancelled) onChangeImage(result.uri);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error reading an image", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handlePress}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {!imageUri && <Icon color="gray" name="camera" size={40} />}
        {imageUri && <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={styles.image} />}
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
export default ImageInput;
```

**The list that is made up of these ImageInputs (ImageInputList.js):**

```
function ImageInputList({ imageUris = [], onRemoveImage, onAddImage }) {
  const scrollView = useRef();

  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView
        ref={scrollView}
        horizontal
        onContentSizeChange={() => scrollView.current.scrollToEnd()}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {imageUris.map((uri) => (
            <View key={uri} style={styles.image}>
              <ImageInput
                imageUri={uri}
                onChangeImage={() => onRemoveImage(uri)}
              />
            </View>
          ))}
          <ImageInput onChangeImage={(uri) => onAddImage(uri)} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**The combination of the previous component, and an error message so that I can use the component in a form easier (FormImagePicker.js):**

```
export default function FormImagePicker({ name }) {
  const { errors, setFieldValue, touched, values } = useFormikContext();
  const imageUris = values[name];

  const handleAdd = (uri) => {
    setFieldValue(name, [...imageUris, uri]);
  };

  const handleRemove = (uri) => {
    setFieldValue(
      name,
      imageUris.filter((imageUri) => imageUri !== uri)
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ImageInputList
        imageUris={imageUris}
        onAddImage={handleAdd}
        onRemoveImage={handleRemove}
      />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
    </>
  );
}
```

**The relevant part of the screen this is being implemented on (ListingEditScreen) **

```
function ListingEditScreen(props) {
  return (
    <SafeScreen style={styles.container}>
      <AppForm
        initialValues={{
          title: "",
          price: "",
          description: "",
          category: null,
          images: [],
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
      >
        <FormImagePicker name="images" />
        <AppFormField
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          keyboardType="default"
          maxLength={255}
          name="title"
          placeholder="Title"
        />
```

**This is the error that is thrown in the ImageInput component:***
This is printed in the selectImage function, but the spread operator is located in the component FormImagePicker.

```
Error reading an image [TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.]
```